# Getting fall back icon with Font awesome

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I keep getting the fallback icon "fl" though I'm doing everything right based on my research:

```
 <div class="propertySearch">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
    <input placeholder="City, Zip or Street..." type="text">
 </div>


 .propertySearch input { text-indent: 32px;}
 .propertySearch .fa-search { 
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 left: 10px;
 color: black;
 font-size: 30px;
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Your HTML looks fine, how did you import Font Awesome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show how you have imported the css file?

It should be like : `<link href="path/to/yourfile/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: I did have the link point to my local font-awesome.min.css file but it wouldn't work. Placing <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> right underneath did the trick

Comment: Your path is likely to be wrong, which is why it didn't work for the local copy of the css file. If both the html and the css are in the same directory, then all you'd have to do is include the files name like ....href="font-awesome.min.css". For future debugging, (if you are developing in Chrome), inspect the page and select the 'Network' tab which will give you a list of all the files that page is calling. You can check if you've accurately called the local file. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to import the css file for the `font-awesome`

```css
.propertySearch input {
  text-indent: 32px;
}

.propertySearch .fa-search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="propertySearch">
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
  <input placeholder="City, Zip or Street..." type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Yup you are right! I was pulling in <link href="resources/css/fontawesome-all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> locally but placing <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> right below did the trick!!

Comment: @insivika yes your path may be wrong check that one and do accept the answer for future reference to others :)